# Perform COUNT based on data from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am still new to SQL, and performing basic functions is challenging, so I apologize if this is a basic question.

I am have several tables with 2 being CUSTOMER and ORDERS. I need to get a count of how many orders each customer has placed. I am trying this code and it fails:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || CUSTOMER.LASTNAME as CUSTOMER,
       COUNT(ORDERS.ORDERID) as ORDERS
  FROM customer
 INNER JOIN orders
    ON customer.CUSTOMERID = orders.CUSTOMERID
 GROUP BY CUSTOMER;
```

Can someone tell me where to correct my statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you want looks like this:

```
SELECT c.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || c.LASTNAME as CUSTOMER, COUNT(o.ORDERID) as NumOrders
FROM CUSTOMER c LEFT JOIN
     ORDERS o
     ON c.CUSTOMERID = o.CUSTOMERID
GROUP BY c.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || c.LASTNAME;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Oracle doesn't support column aliases in `GROUP BY`.  You need to repeat the expression (or use a subquery or CTE).
- If you want all customers, then use `LEFT JOIN`  This will include all customers, even those with no orders.

EDIT:

The answer to the question in your comment:

```
SELECT c.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || c.LASTNAME as CUSTOMER, COUNT(o.ORDERID) as NumOrders
FROM CUSTOMER c LEFT JOIN
     ORDERS o
     ON c.CUSTOMERID = o.CUSTOMERID
GROUP BY c.FIRSTNAME, c.LASTNAME
ORDER BY c.LASTNAME;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, How how I get it to sort ASC by c.lastname? I tried adding ASC to the Group By statement but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This could be more easier to understand. The result will be a little different as below will include customers without order as well (ORDERS value will be 0). No difference in performance I believe.

```
select
    CUSTOMER.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || CUSTOMER.LASTNAME as CUSTOMER
    ,(
        select COUNT (ORDERS.ORDERID)
        from ORDERS
        where ORDERS.CUSTOMERID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID
    ) ORDERS
from
    CUSTOMER
```